# How to querySelector elements of an element's DOM using Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have my element :

```
<dom-module id="x-el">
  <p class="special-paragraph">first paragraph</p>
  <content></content>
</dom-module>
```

and I use it like

```
<x-el>
  <p class="special-paragraph">second paragraph</p>
</x-el>
```

in my imperative part:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-el',

  ready: function () {
    /* this will select all .special-paragraph in the light DOM
       e.g. 'second paragraph' */
    Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('.special-paragraph');

    /* this will select all .special-paragraph in the local DOM
       e.g. 'first paragraph' */
    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.special-paragraph');

    /* how can I select all .special-paragraph in both light DOM and
       local DOM ? */
  }
});
```

Is it possible to do that using Polymer built-in's ?
Or should I use the default DOM api ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Polymer does **not** provide a helper function or abstraction that will list nodes both from the light **and** local DOMs.

If you require this functionality, you can use `this.querySelector(selector)`.

On a side note, aside from the `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(selector)` method, Polymer also provides the `$$` utility function which helps in accessing members of an element's local DOM. This function is used as follows:

```html
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <p class="special-paragraph">...</p>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    ready: {
      this.$$('.special-paragraph'); // Will return the <p> in the local DOM
    }
  });
</script>
```

Note that, unlike `querySelectorAll`, the `$$` function only returns one element: the **first** element in the local DOM which matches the selector.

Comment: might be worth clarifying that `this.$$.(selector)` returns the **first** node in the elements **local DOM** that matches the `selector`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @benhjt! I threw in the clarification. :)

Comment: @VartanSimonian thanks for the solution ! I think it is an obscure trait of Polymer. `this` refers to the element, then why `Polymer.dom(this)` is used to manipulate only the light DOM ? I think it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @발렌탕 I can see how it can get a little befuddling! I certainly get tangled up sometimes. One way to think of it is that `this` always, as you've correctly noted, always refers to the element itself. `Polymer.dom(...)` is a wrapper of sorts that makes sure that, when you're modifying the DOM, it gets modified properly, regardless of whether you give it `this`, which will edit the light DOM, or `this.root` to tap into the local DOM. The standard DOM has no idea about what Polymer is doing, hence this wrapper! If I answered your question to your liking, would you mind marking it as an answer? :)

Comment: @VartanSimonian thanks again my dear man, that was sure helpful, keeping on tracks of the nice Polymer's talks !

Comment: So this.$.special-paragraph would NOT work here, because this.$ only works for IDs, while this.$$() also works for classes?

Comment: @BenThomas IINM, that should be this.$$(selector) - ie no '.' between '$$' and '('.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can keep in mind is this one:

```
var elements = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("input")
```

Comment: My question was about Polymer 1