# Running a selector on, and visiting, the light DOM tree

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

I have a widget like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hot-network">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <content id="content"></content>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'hot-network',

      attached: function(){
        var form = this.queryEffectiveChildren( 'iron-form');
        var paperInput = this.queryEffectiveChildren( 'paper-input');

        console.log("WIDGETS:", ironAjaxWidgets );
    },


    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I want to use this widget like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-view2">

  <template>

    <hot-network>
      <div>
        <form is="iron-form" id="form" on-iron-form-response="_response" method="PUT" action="/stores/polymer">
          <paper-input required id="name" name="name" label="Your name"></paper-input>
          <paper-button raised type="submit">Click!</paper-button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </hot-network>
  </template>

  <script>


    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view2',
      _response: function(){
        console.log("AH!");
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

## QUESTION 1: How do I look for elements (using a selector) in the light DOM?

These two calls effectively don't work:

```
var form = this.queryEffectiveChildren( 'iron-form');
var paperInput = this.queryEffectiveChildren( 'paper-input');
```

Since they only run the selector on the "first level" of the effective children.

If I need to look for widgets in the distributed content (important for composition), how can I do it reliably?

## QUESTION 2: What's the best way to visit all effective children?

I have come up with this code, but it's borderline obscene... I cannot even look at it without feeling funny in my stomach!

```
  attached: function(){
    this.async( function(){


      function inspect( e ){
        console.log("INSPECTING", e );
      }

      this.getEffectiveChildren().forEach( (effectiveChild) => {
        console.log("Effective child found.");
        inspect( effectiveChild );
        console.log("Getting into all children of it...");
        var foundChildren = effectiveChild.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for( var i = 0, l = foundChildren.length; i < l; i ++ ){
          var child = foundChildren[ i ];
          inspect( child );
        };
        console.log("All children inspected!");
      });

    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

```
var form = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#form');
// or
var form = this.$$('#form');
// or if you wanna use tags/attributes
var form = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('form[is="iron-form"]');
```

Querying for the paper-input is similar to the above.

Comment: You do realise I am running queries on the light DOM, not the local DOM, right?

Comment: My point is that your selectors are wrong. And if you are not having the same object types inside and outside the ```<content>``` of your element local DOM and light DOM barely make a difference in selecting child nodes. Furthermore your light DOM is empty by definition. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638632/how-to-queryselector-elements-of-an-elements-dom-using-polymer